# Streaming movie from Galaxy S5 to TV, through laptop?

Tags: bluetooth, streaming, screen-sharing, video-streaming, google-play-movies

**Summary**: I want to stream Google Play movie from Android to HDMI/VGA/Composite TV, possibly through laptop.

I have no idea whether it's possible or not but I'd really love some insight from some more knowledgeable people on.

More in depth: I have a Galaxy S5, unrooted, that I absolutely love. First smart phone, I've been living off of a talk/text only phone previously. I also recently came home for the holidays to discover that my sister hasn't seen the Lord of the Rings! I figured I'd be smart, and use my Google Play account (with all three extended editions) to stream it through my laptop, and laptop to TV. Well, the internet here is very poor, I guess my parents get about .6 MBps? Anyways, video streaming kept buffering/loading, so I tried to move over to my phone, which has all three already downloaded into internal storage. Couldn't find a way to stream from phone to TV, the USB port wasn't gonna work. I don't have an adapter, but I do have my laptop. I tried pulling the downloaded .wvm file from the phone, but because yay DRM, that's a no go. I've done some searching, and while the AndroidScreencast project seems promising, it says it refreshes at about 5 FPS, so not very good for media streaming.

So I have a phone, a laptop, and a TV. I can connect the phone to the laptop by USB or Bluetooth. Laptop to TV via HDMI or VGA. Is there any way I can play the movie on my phone, have it feeding the video to the TV/laptop, and then to the TV?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site anymore after posting the question, and no answers have score more than 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can because there are many interfaces in the middle. I don't think there's an app for doing that. What I strongly suggest you is buying the Google's Chromecast. With that $35 stick you'd avoid the using of your laptop and you'd stream directly to your TV.

There are a lot of apps for Chromecast out there, it's a whole new world because Chromecast is a whole new concept.

[Videostream](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.videostream.Mobile) is one of the apps you can use for streaming from your smartphone or laptop directly to your TV (well, directly to your Chromecast, but it's connected via HDMI so it's the same) and controlling the play, pause, seekbar and even the volume.

Answer (score 0):

Get an USB hml cable to hook up your phone to the tv: http://www.amazon.it/gp/aw/d/0283382155/ref=mp_s_a_1_6?qid=1419720244&sr=8-6&pi=SL75

Comment: It seems that the link you provide is in non-English (Italian). Please try to use the English version. And also, showing an example is good, but try not to direct link a specific product as it can be considered as purely promotional (spam). You can instead put an image instead, or provide the keyword (which you've already done)

Comment: Doh, I forgot i'm italian. My intent was totally not promotional, I just grabbed the first of the list. Next time I will be more carefull.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is get your computer to play the content from your phone.  Try Sidesync if you are a samsung user.  VLC Direct Pro is a great way to stream content from your phone onto your computer.
Now that your computer is playing content from your phone, connect your Laptop to an external display via an HDMI or (sigh) VGA cable.